# What happens if I rewrite the acceleration in work formula this way?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, acceleration, work

Work is known as
\begin{equation}
W=\vec{F}.\vec{q},
\end{equation}
thus for a gravitational force $\vec{F}_g=m\vec{g}$ we have
\begin{equation}
W=mgh.
\end{equation}

My derivation is as follows:
\begin{equation}
dW=\vec{F}_g\cdot d\vec{q}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\implies W=\int_0^h\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{q}=\int_0^hm\vec{g}\cdot d\vec{q}=mg\int_0^h dq=mgh.
\end{equation}
Now consider a spring force
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}_s=-k\vec{q}.
\end{equation}
Inserting this into the first equation gives
\begin{equation}
W=-k\int_0^x \vec{q}\cdot d\vec{q}=-k\frac{x^2}{2}.
\end{equation}
Using
\begin{equation}
v^2-v_0^2=-2gq
\end{equation}
I rewrite the acceleration in $F_g$:
$$F_g=m\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2q}$$
and insert it into the equation of work:
$$W=\int m\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2q}dq=m\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2}\int\frac{dq}{q}=m\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2}\ln|q|\neq mgh.$$
I want to know which part is wrong and why. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can't pull out $v$ since it depends on $q$

Comment: In the integral over q, v is not a constant so you can't take it outside the integral. v is a function of the integration variable, q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the integral
$$
\int m \frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2q}dq
$$
$v$ is a function of $q$, since $v$ changes over the range of integration.  So it cannot be treated like a constant and cannot be pulled out of the integral as you have done.

In fact, as you showed, $v^2 = v_0^2 + 2 q g$, and so the integrand simplifies to $mg$ and the integral is just $W = \int mg \, dq$.

Comment: But $g$ is a function of $q$, how do we get $mgh$ in my first derivation, if I have done that correctly?

Comment: $g$ is assumed to be a constant here

Comment: the quantity $\dfrac{v^2 - v_0^2}{2q}$ is constant and equals g.  so, technically, you can pull that whole thing out of your integral if you want (which is just equivalent to pulling out a g)

Comment: @user256872 So if the whole thing is constant, we don't care about it and pull it out of the integral, but if we simply rewrite it and see that it has some functions that cannot be pulled out, we care, until it is rewritten that way. Let's say someone doesn't know if $g$ is constant. Instead, they only know it is $\frac{v^2-v_0^2}{2q}$, solving it doesn't give $w=mgh$.

Comment: The equation you used is derived assuming the acceleration is constant, youve supplied the assumption that g is already constant.

Comment: @Ray:  To do the integral, you need to know how $v$ varies as a function of $q$.  Without knowing that, the equation is correct, it's just that you can't perform the integral$$\int \frac{v^2(q) - v_0^2}{2q} \, dq.$$